# need explanation about the answer on this for loop

Tags: java, arrays, loops

Iam Learning java and I cant figure out why in the code above the answer is 20:

```
    int arrays[]={1,2,3,4,5};
    int x = 4;
    int y = 0;
    for(int i=0; i < 5; i++){
     y+=arrays[x-i]*i;
    } 
    System.out.println(y);
```

can I get explain please
thanks :)

Comment: why don't you print out each value you add. that way it should be more clear

Comment: Why don't you use a debugger of some sort? Or at least try to print out all the numbers that are added. That help a lot if you're not sure what is going on.

Comment: You should try first, If you have read and tried please mention your findings with the question

Comment: I am new .. I dont really know all the tricks and tips to understand things that are not clear to me but thanks I'll will try to use it when I need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I Debug it for you !

y = y + [4-0] ~ 5 * 0 => 0

0 = 0 + [4-1] ~ 4 * 1 => 4

4 = 4 + [4-2] ~ 3 * 2 => 10

10 = 10 + [4-3] ~ 2 * 3 = > 16

16 = 16 + [4-4] ~ 1 * 4 => 20

Comment: First Thank you but what is the ~5 ~4 ~3 ~2 ~1  I know its the array but why its from 5 to 1 and not 1 to 5

Comment: where the answer of this little section [x-i] goes? to the next loop ?

Answer (score 2):

If you write this snippet in the beginning of your for loop

```
System.out.println("y=" + y + "+" + arrays[x-i] + "*" + i + " => " + (y + arrays[x-i] * i));
```

... you get this output:

```
y=0+5*0 => 0
y=0+4*1 => 4
y=4+3*2 => 10
y=10+2*3 => 16
y=16+1*4 => 20
```

Comment: Thank you :) but how its possible to "pass" the [x-i] section in the output ?
its make the calculate and output the answer of it? or where is it